# Google Maps JavaScript API change zoom level after search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I would like to change the zoom level and min/max zoom levels AFTER a search is performed:

```
function initMap() {

    var myLatLng = {
        lat: 38.5803844, 
        lng: -121.50024189999999
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      minZoom: 16,
      maxZoom: 17,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeControl: false
    });

}

function getDirectionsHere(lat,lng) {

    map.setMinZoom(10);
    map.setZoom(10);

}
```

The code above changes the zoom level when a user performs a search, however it only zooms out as far as what was initially set in the initMap function (16).

map.setMinZoom is not a function it seems.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

maps.SetOptions did the trick:

```
map.setOptions({ minZoom: 5, maxZoom: 15 });
```

Comment: Yes this solves the issue but it creates a new problem in that the max zoom is limited now so after search if the user wants to zoom more they can't.

Comment: You would probably be better asking a new question with your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum zoom level is able to be retrieved using [MaxZoomService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom#MaxZoomResponses).

So this should work.

```
function initMap() {

    var myLatLng = {
        lat: 38.5803844, 
        lng: -121.50024189999999
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      minZoom: 16,
      maxZoom: 17,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeControl: false
    });

    maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();
}

function getDirectionsHere(lat,lng) {

    maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng({lat, lng}, function(response) {
        map.setOptions({ minZoom: 5, maxZoom: response.zoom });
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
}
```